# The ?PATTERN? operator is not working for Matching Only Once in Perl

Tags: perl

I am new to Perl and am practising some programs. I have encountered a syntax error. Please help me.

#### My Perl program

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

@list = qw/ food foosball subeo footnote terfoot canic footbridge /;

foreach ( @list ) {
    $first = $1 if ?(foo.*)?;
    $last  = $1 if /(foo.*)/;
}

print "First: $first, Last: $last\n";
```

#### Output

```
syntax error at MatchingOnlyOnce.pl line 9, near "if ?"
Execution of MatchingOnlyOnce.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

#### Output of `perl -v`

```
This is perl 5, version 24, subversion 1 (v5.24.1) built for MSWin32-x64-multi-t
hread

Copyright 1987-2017, Larry Wall

Perl may be copied only under the terms of either the Artistic License or the
GNU General Public License, which may be found in the Perl 5 source kit.

Complete documentation for Perl, including FAQ lists, should be found on
this system using "man perl" or "perldoc perl".  If you have access to the
Internet, point your browser at http://www.perl.org/, the Perl Home Page.
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and format it properly. Make each piece of code an individual code block. We can't understand exactly what is code and what is text. Your code obviously has syntax errors. `$first=$1 if ?(foo.*)?;` is not valid syntax. Probably their online compiler does not complain because it's not a compiler, just some very simple text parser that doesn't understand full Perl syntax. The error message you are getting is actually pretty clear. Also, always start your programs with `use strict;` and `use warnings;`. Those help you to spot errors early on.

Comment: @simbabque, It was valid syntax until 5.22

Answer (score 8):

Use

```
$first=$1 if m?(foo.*)?;
```

`?PATTERN?` could be used as a shortcut for `m?PATTERN?`, but you can no longer omit the match operator's leading `m` when you use `?` as the delimiter.

---

5.14 deprecated the ability to omit the leading `m` from `m?PATTERN?flags`.

5.22 removed the ability to omit the leading `m` from `m?PATTERN?flags`.

5.22 and 5.24's perlop lists both `m?PATTERN?flags` and `?PATTERN?flags`, but only the former if legal in these versions.

5.26's documentation will be free of all mentions of `?PATTERN?` (as opposed to `m?PATTERN?`).

Comment: The documentation has been fixed. I think you'll find the fix in 5.26 (but maybe not since it's very late in the release process).

Answer (score 7):

If you are not using the default `/` pattern delimiters, you *must* specify the match operation as in `$x =~ m{...}`, `$x =~ m!...!` etc.

`?...?` is different than those other alternative delimiters as `?...?` does something different than `/.../`. `perldoc perlreref` currently states:

> `?pattern?` is like `m/pattern/` but matches only once. No alternate delimiters can be used. Must be reset with `reset()`.

That is [misleading](http://www.nntp.perl.org/group/perl.perl5.porters/2017/04/msg244142.html) as Perl *used to* recognize the plain `?...?`, but support for that [was completely removed](http://www.nntp.perl.org/group/perl.perl5.porters/2014/01/msg211101.html) a few years ago:

> **[perl #120912] [PATCH] Remove support for ?PATTERN? without explicit 'm' operator**
>
> …
>
> This has issued a deprecation warning since Perl v5.14 (commit
>   [725a61d70](https://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/commit/725a61d70)), and precludes using ? as an operator after a unary operator
>   that defaults to $_, such as:
>
> ```
> ref ? $_ : [$_]
> ```

Here is the motivation for the deprecation and eventual removal:

> Deprecate `?PATTERN?`, recommending the equivalent `m?PATTERN?` syntax, in
>   order to eventually allow the question mark to be used in new operators
>   that would currently be ambiguous.

If you are just beginning to learn Perl, you ought to enable `strict` and `warnings`. Declare your variables in the smallest applicable scope.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @list = qw/food foosball subeo footnote terfoot canic footbridge/;
my ($first, $last);

foreach my $item (@list) {
    $item =~ m?(foo.*)?
        and $first = $1;
    $item =~ /(foo.*)/
        and $last = $1;
}
print "First: $first, Last: $last\n";
```

Output:

```
$ perl tt.pl
First: food, Last: footbridge
```

Answer (score 0):

A lot of things about Perl are unusual for a programming language, and you have happened upon a corner of the language that is rarely used

Perl was designed by a the linguist [**Larry Wall**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larry_Wall), and there are many similarities between Perl and spoken languages. Perl allows abbreviations of some constructs, for instance, a pattern match like

```
/abc/
```

is equivalent to

```
$_ =~ m/abc/
```

That is to say, if it *looks like* a regex pattern it will be treated as one, regardless of whether the leading `m` is there or not. Also, many Perl operators work on `$_` by default, which allows you to write a few lines of code without explicitly mentioning a variable

But `m?...?` is an old-fashioned construct that has really been edged out by *lexical variables*. If you declare a variable using `my` then there is no need for the one-shot match, or the corresponding `reset` operator. It is your declaration that defines the lifetime of the variable

If you are just starting with Perl, I recommend that you

- ***Always*** start *every* program with `use strict` and `use warnings 'all'`. This isn't optional as it's the first line of defence against simple mistakes and errors
- ***Always*** declare every variable using `my` as close as possible to its first use. Occasionally you may want to declare variables before a loop so that its value is kept across iterations, but generally variables should be temporary and useful only for a few lines of code
- Forget about `m?...?`. I have never seen a program that uses it in twenty years of writing Perl professionally

I hope this helps

Comment: Thanks Borodin. Yes definitely will follow now on wards.